# Inline form foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a project and I need to make an inline-form with foundation. The problem is that labels are above of input and I want to have label inline with inputs. Here is the code for the moment:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-x small-x">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-3 rows">
                  <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Login</label>           
                </div>
                <div class="small-3 columns">
                  <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="ex:toto">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-x small-x">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-3 rows">
                    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="small-3 columns">
                    <input type="password" id="right-label" placeholder="password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is the link of the fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/705/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="small-3 rows">
  <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Login</label>
</div>
```

Your `div` class should be `columns` instead of `rows`

Watch the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/713/) :

Comment: Have you removed `rows` and added `columns` instead, only on the `small-3` div ?

Comment: Yes I do, I still have the issue

Comment: Did you provide us the whole html page ? Maybe some of your divs aren't closed.

Comment: You also have to remember that `foundation` grids are divided in 12 columns. Your elements should match 12 columns. So if you've got a label that is two columns width, you should have an input of ten columns width. See the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLk0jf4L/722/)